# Load candlestick data from file

Tags: delphi, teechart

I am starting to play with TChart component from Steema software. Does anyone have an example demonstrating how to load candlestick data from an text file and to show the following values when the user moves his cursor over a certain day:

- Open
- Close
- Low
- High
- Volume

Comment: Asking for example code is off-topic.  Suggest you review the documentation : http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/vclfmx/tutorials/index.html

Answer (score 2):

To obtain data from a text file into a chart, check out the *All Features\Welcome!\Components\Text Source* examples in the new features demo, available at TeeChart's program group. You can also find an example [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?t=5313&highlight=seriestextsource1).

To display the values when the mouse hovers the candles, use MarksTip tool and the [OnGetText event](http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/vclfmx/lib/html/TMarksTipTool.OnGetText.html) to customize marks.